# Inform Google of video sitemap update

Tags: php, unix, sitemap, ping

I read somewhere that you can let Google know of a new addition to your sitemap by simply opening the following url

```
http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap=http://www.mysite.com/sitemap.xml
```

What is the best way to do this in a php script on a nix server? I don't need any response back from the ping either, I am pretty sure that Google will not be blocked and it will be available.
Thanks

Comment: Not a programming question. Voting to move to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple, one-line script that uses `wget` to access the URL (`wget -qO- "http://..." >/dev/null`), and place it in crontab to have it run once every N hours or days.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a script already that adds an entry to my sitemap as soon as a video is added, after it has done this I would like it to simply ping Google that there is an update. So I would not need a cron to do the job. I am thinking something like using a shell_exec command at the end of the sitemap building script I already have but don't know what command I should be putting in it, or even if that is the best way to go. So do you think a wget is the right choice in a shell_exec?

Comment: @JizboJonez, if you want to do this in PHP, you can simply use [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php#refsect1-function.curl-exec-examples) to make the request whenever you need to. Do make sure though to not flood Google with ping requests if you change the sitemap often, otherwise you might get banned...

Comment: oh ok, so that would make Google hate my site then I take it? So what is a good curl command? I have no experience using it. Would Google keep coming back to check the sitemap without me doing this anyway? After your comment I am thinking it is not such a great idea even though I read [here](http://yoast.com/video-seo/) that I should do it every time. "While you can submit it manually, you can also ping Google with the URL of the sitemap every time you’ve updated it" I would have updates every couple of minutes at the moment.

Comment: @JizboJonez, try clicking on "cURL" in the previous comment to see an example of how to use it. Sending requests every couple of minutes might not be the best of ideas... If I were to do this, I'd probably only send them out once an hour. These ping requests do however look like hints more than anything (certainly not commands), so it's possible that whatever the number of pings you send, the robots will visit rarely and only if they choose to.

Comment: ok cool, I didn't see that link the first time sorry, thanks for pointing it out. For now I will see how Google goes checking my sitemap in it's own time, if it's not often enough I'll look at doing a curl command one every hour or so as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Issue your request to the following URL:www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap=sitemap_url

Issue the HTTP request using wget, curl, or another mechanism of your choosing.
A successful request will return an HTTP 200 response code, if you receive a different response, you should resubmit your request.